# JQuery - Remove dynamic contents on page load?

Tags: jquery

How to remove dynamically generated text on page load event with jQuery?
I tried google but nothing found useful. Actually i am using a third party JS library which inserts some text on html page which i need to remove.

I tried this code but it removes the constant text which is already in html page not dynamic text.

```
$('div:contains("Powered by")').remove();
```

**Edit:**

Here is the full code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="translate">
    <div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
     new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en',includedLanguages: 'en,es,fr,it'}, 'google_translate_element');
 }
   </script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
  </div>
   </body>
    </html>
```

**Note:** Google translator adds select box which i need but adds some text 'Powered by' below it which i want to remove. Although, it is possible to hide the text with css but i want to remove it with jQuery.

Comment: Can you create fiddle. So that we can check.

Comment: Maybe you should put this code into an interval like,

var interval_of_function = setInterval(function(){ $('div:contains("Powered by")').remove(); } , 100);

Comment: is it the best solution for this question? I think not because it may have more resources. @esertbas

Comment: Well M.Tanzil exaplains well and it should work unless your powered by text applied after some time. try this code; it will loop until it finds "Powered By" than stops.

var interval_of_function = setInterval(function(){ var query = $('div:contains("Powered by")'); if(query.length>0) { query.remove(); } else{ clearInterval(interval_of_function); }  } , 100);

Comment: I've edited my question. See the full code. setInterval not working.

Answer (score 2):

***UPDATE***

Another solution, is:

```js
$(window).on('load', function(e) {
  $('div.skiptranslate.goog-te-gadget').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="translate">
    <div id="google_translate_element">This is a simple snippet</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en',includedLanguages: 'en,es,fr,it'}, 'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

***Old Answer***

You may use the [DOMNodeInserted mutation event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) to check if under one of your div is present the text you are looking for:

```js
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', 'div:contains("Powered By")', function(e) {
  console.log('element div conatining "Powered By" removed!');
  $(this).remove();
});
$(function () {
  $('#addText').on('click', function(e) {
    $('div').append('Powered By');
  });
  $('#addDiv').on('click', function(e) {
    $('body').before('<div>..................</div>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<div>Powered By</div>
<div>Powered By</div>
<div>Powered By</div>
<button id="addText">Add text</button>
<button id="addDiv">Add div</button>
```

Comment: worked like a charm. The only thing i changed it to put your code in $(document).ready(function(){     $(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', 'div:contains("Powered By")', function(e) {
  console.log('element div conatining "Powered By" removed!');
  $(this).remove();
}); });

Answer (score 0):

In page load event or `window` load event it won't work because your `DOM` is not ready yet, mean the `div` with text `Powered by` is not there, and your `code` is executing before that, you have to put your code in `DOM` ready function below that line where this Powered By is generated.

**NOTE** Check your **brsower console** for `errors` if there is none then it will work

**LIKE**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div:contains('Powered By')").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Powered By</div>
```

Then it will work.

Comment: use single quotes around `Powered By`, also check snippet,
you may check your browser console for errors, there may be errors.

Comment: Go through my question again. It's about dynamically generated text not a static text already on page.

Comment: Then place that line below that line where this `Powered By` is generated, or use `setInterval`.